# How to remove the log of Chrome web driver and IE web driver

Tags: java, selenium

I am developing a tool using selenium chrome web driver. That should display only the result on the console. But during initialization it print some error logs. My problem is to how to remove these logs.

```
WebDriver driver=new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

In this case it is showing the log

```
 Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)
  2.24.2.0
 Listening on port 41437
```

And for the chrome

```
 WebDriver driver =new ChromeDriver();
```

And the log is

```
  Started ChromeDriver
  port=42458
  version=21.0.1180.4
  log=G:\Workspace_Selenium\WebTestSelenium_ToResolveTheReview\chromedriver.log
```

Looking for help

Comment: Can you please clarify what exactly you are trying to remove? Do you want the console not to print the information that you pasted above when it starts up, or do you want the web driver to not keep a log file?

Comment: Information i.e. printed on the console

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using any kind of logging other than the console (or manage it yourself), then

```
Logger shutUp = Logger.getLogger("");
shutUp.setLevel(Level.WARNING);
```

does the job. That should only output warnings. You can, of course, use `Level.SEVERE` to make it only output errors or even `Level.OFF` to be absolutely quiet.

Comment: Use Level.OFF but it is still printing the LOG

Comment: maybe the logger's name isn't `""`?